# There are too few things to do after work

Tags: sentence-meaning

> There are **too few things to do** after work.

Can we say that sentence has only a positive or negative connotation? As I understand that sentence, it can mean:

1. with a positive connotation - "there are almost nothing to do after (my) work and after that I'm free and able to do other things"
2. with a negative connotation - "there are almost nothing to do after work (in this town) and I’m bored."

Is that a correct interpretation of the sentence? (The sentence is from a grammar book.)

Comment: 'Too' before an adjective, adverb, e.g. too few, too many, too small, too large, too heavy, etc, is always negative and is used to indicate that there is a problem or issue, that something is not right, acceptable, suitable, manageable, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a negative connotation, consistent with your interpretation 2.

However since "having free time" is usually considered positive, there is an ironic aspect.  A sentence can be ironic if it describes in a negative way something that would normally be considered good.

It could have a simple, non-ironic  in some context in which after-work activities are provided for the staff.  Eg on a ship.

Comment: Could you tell me, a sentence "There aren’t enough things to do after work." is similar in their meaning with the sentence in the post? "Too" & "Enough" don't usually have the same meaning, but in this case they do. Right?

Comment: "not enough" and "too few"  normally have the same or similar meaning.  So "There aren’t enough things to do after work"  has a similar meaning